# integration of a multi-variable function.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was studying fluid mechanics, and I came across an integration of a multi-variable function.

The question was, what is

$\int x \mathrm{dz}$ (when z = $x^2 + y^2$) ?

Using WolframAlpha, the result is JUST $\int\ x dz$ (when z = $x^2 + y^2$) = '$xz + Constant$'
[enter link description here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3D%20x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%2C%20int%20x%20dz)

- it considered $x$ being a constant, and integrate as indicated.

$\int\ x dz$ = $x\int\ dz$ = $xz + Constant$

---

In my opinion, $z$ is 'multi-variable' function of '$x$' and '$y$'
and it means that when z changes, x and y changes respectively.

(if $z$ increases from zero to $z$, then $x$ and $y$ also increases from zero to x and y)

and the change of z can be expressed with 'total derivative' ($\large{dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy}$)

using this,  i get $\int\ x dz$ = ${\int}\ x ( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy) =\int x (2xdx + 2ydy) = \int 2x^2dx + \int 2xydy  = \frac{1}{3}x^3 +xy^2 + Constant$

Why is this process wrong? Why considering the change of $x$ with $\mathrm{dz}$ makes integration wrong?

Comment: The second argument is correct. You did not explain to Wolfram Alpha correctly that $z$ was dependent on $x$.

Comment: The underlying assumption is x and y are independent variables and z is a dependent variable on x and y, so the WA explanation makes sense. However, I believe your method should also give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

When $z(x,y):=x^2+y^2$ then $dz=2x\,dx+2y\,dy$, and
$$\omega:=x\>dz=2x^2\,dx+2xy\,dy$$
is a *differential $1$-form* on the $(x,y)$-plane. When $$\gamma:\quad[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad t\mapsto \gamma(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$$
is a curve in the plane then one can compute the *line integral*
$$\int_\gamma\omega\ :=\ \int_a^b \bigl(2x^2(t)x'(t)+2x(t)y(t)y'(t)\bigr)\>dt\ .$$
The value of this integral is independent of the parametrization used for $\gamma$.

On the other hand the given typographical painting
$$\int x\>dz$$
has no mathematical sense.